# Visual Basic - Input multidimensional array dimensions from console

Tags: vb.net, matrix, multidimensional-array

Essentially, I'm trying to write a small console application that will multiply matrices, represented with 2D arrays in the code. I want the matrix dimensions to be decided via console input.

Is it possible to do this without using "If" branching for every possible/allowed number of rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the dimensions as `Integer` variables

```
Dim s As String = Console.ReadLine()
Dim m As Integer = Integer.Parse(s)

s = Console.ReadLine()
Dim n As Integer = Integer.Parse(s)

Dim matrix = New Double(m - 1, n - 1) 'Creates matrix with m rows and n columns.
```

Note that in VB you don't specify the size of the array or matrix but its upper index. So if you want an index range of 0 ... m - 1 and 0 ... n - 1, you must write `New Double(m - 1, n - 1)`. This is unlike C# where you specify the sizes. The C# equivalent is `new double[m, n]`.

See also: [Arrays in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/)

Comment: Won't that create an array with m-1 elements in the first row and n-1 elements in the second row?

Comment: No, as in VB you specify the highest index, not the size.

Comment: From the link, declaring an array with [5,5] creates an array of 6 *6 size

Comment: That means that we can use arr [5,5] in such cases

Comment: And it does not declare the first and second row but the highest index of a 2D structure horizontally (m - 1) and vertically (n - 1). But which one you consider as horizontal and which one as vertical is up to you. So you declare rows and columns, not 1st row and 2nd row.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thank you for clearing that up. My confusion stemmed from a fundamental misunderstanding of how the constructor for arrays works.